# Targeting specific index in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently building a crud application in VueJS and need to perform an update action in the database.

I pull in all the documents in a collection as follows:

```html
<div class="events" v-for="(event, index) in GETEVENTS" :key="index">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Name: <strong v-if="!change">{{event.name}}</strong><input v-else v-model="event.name"></li>
    <li>Location: <strong v-if="!change">{{event.location}}</strong><input v-else v-model="event.location"></li>
    <li>Capacity: <strong v-if="!change">{{event.qty}}</strong><input v-else v-model="event.qty"></li>
    <li>Price: <strong v-if="!change">${{event.price}}</strong><input v-else v-model="event.price"></li>
    <li>Description: <strong v-if="!change">{{event.description}}</strong><textarea v-else v-model="event.description"></textarea></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="edit" @click="change = !change">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete" @click.prevent="DELETEEVENT(event._id)">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the elements appear in a list format, and within the list I have added inputs that only show when the variable `change` is `true`.

However, since that variable is global, ALL inputs are shown for ALL array items. How can I target one specific array item using this method?

I have the delete functionality down perfectly. It is the updating that is giving me problems.

I am open to other methods if they are easier/better.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: each event should have his own change property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your `change` variable from a Boolean to a representation of the `event._id` you want to edit.

```js
data: () => ({
  change: null // start with null,
  GETEVENTS: [] // or whatever you currently have
})
```

Then set that ID via your *Edit* button

```html
<button class="edit" @click="change = event._id">Edit</button>
```

Toggle the inputs by comparing `change` to the `event._id`

```html
<strong v-if="event._id = change">
```

---

Finally, you use the `event._id` as your `:key` binding to have Vue better track which object its working on

```html
<div class="events" v-for="event in GETEVENTS" :key="event._id">
```

This is particularly useful if you start sorting or filtering the list of events.

Comment: @RizaKhan great! Glad I could help